# Address of NULL pointer

Tags: c, pointers, null

In the below program, I have created a *ptr by assigning NULL to it. As far as I know, *ptr=NULL; means, *ptr is pointing to nothing. If this is the case, why ptr and &ptr giving different results?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

  int *ptr=NULL;

  printf("%p \n",ptr);
  printf("%p \n",&ptr);
}
```

**output:**

```
 0 
 0x7fff3415dc40
```

Comment: you have to store the NULL value right?

Comment: `ptr` is somewhere on the stack. So `&ptr` would point there.

Comment: Yes, my assumption is, &ptr also shall prints 0

Comment: @Henk, you mean, the 0x7fff3415dc40  address is the ptr address which is stored on Stack??

Comment: a NULL pointer is defined to point to address 0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A pointer variable is an **object** that **can** point to another **object**. Here `int *ptr = NULL;` declares `ptr` as a pointer object, that potentially points to an object of `int`.

The value initially stored into *this pointer object* is `NULL` (it is initialized to `NULL`, so `ptr` does not point to any object).

Now, `ptr` too **resides** in memory. It needs enough bytes to contain the address **of the pointed-to object**. So it too needs to have an address. Therefore

- `ptr` evaluates to the address of object that `ptr` points to.
- `&ptr` evaluates to the location of the `ptr` object itself in memory
- `*ptr` evaluates to the **value of the object that `ptr` points to**, if it points to an object. If it does not point to an object, then the behaviour is undefined.

Also, `%p` needs a `void *` as the corresponding argument, therefore the proper way to print them is

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)ptr);
printf("%p\n", (void *)&ptr);
```

Answer (score 7):

`ptr` holds the value `NULL` which is what you assigned.

`&ptr` is the address to the variable `ptr` which in your case is `0x7fff3415dc40`

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is an address. Such address needs memory space to be stored. So a pointer is stored at a specific address.
So &ptr is where the pointer is stored, ptr is the value it points at. So your pointer address is 0x7ff..., and its value is null, iow zero.